# Running pylint causes errors at the end

Tags: python, makefile, pylint

Whenever I run pylint to check my python script for PEP8 standards I get errors at the end.

So, when I run

```
pylint script.py
```

it actually produces the pylint results but at the end also prints the below error:

```
Unable to create directory C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\pylint\pylint\Cache
Unable to create file C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\pylint\pylint\Cache\api1.stats: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\pylint\\pylint\\Cache\\api1.stats'
```

This is a problem as I am trying to run multiple pylints from a makefile and the error stops it after the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/4900, you can create the cache directory yourself first, or wait for the mainstream fix in pylint 2.11.0.

Comment: Thanks, creating the Cache folder manually did remove the error message for now.